# Setting one parse object of type array to a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray, parse-server

I know that I can query for, lets say, users that have emailVerified equal to true and present them into a tableView, but I was having trouble getting a single Parse object of type array into a tableView. I couldn't find anything online about this specific problem, but after putting a few answers together, I got it to work my answer is below for those also having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found based on my question. I have an object in Parse called "my_classes" that is of type array. I want to get the items from the array into a tableView.

1) Create a variable: `var myClassesResults : NSMutableArray = []`

2) Create the function or place the code where necessary:

```
func getUserData() {

    if PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("my_classes") != nil {

        let classes = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("my_classes")!

        myClassesResults = classes as! NSMutableArray

        self.noClasses = false

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    } else {

        self.noClasses = true

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

3) tableView functions:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.myClassesResults.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = myClassesResults[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell

}
```